# Motorcycle turn signal blinking too fast

Tags: motorcycle, turn-signal

I have recently changed my turn signals as a whole as the housing got loose after years of riding. The new turn signals I ordered seem to work good, but they are blinking like 2 or 3 times faster than the previous ones, is there any real reason for this? I guess this will be due to the voltage or smth, I do not really know how the circuit is composed and what the timings depend on.

Comment: Did you unintentionally replace incandescent bulbs with LED or vice-versa?  That can cause the problem you describe.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you seeing the same thing on both sides (left vs right)?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes, I replaced the two front lights, however when I use the old one on one side, that side works just fine, so it only happens when the new is installed.

Comment: @jwh20 definitely possible, will take a look!

Comment: Considering what you said, I'm definitely agreeing with what @jwh20 stated here in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're experiencing what most motorcycle owners would call "hyperflash" - I've dealt with it on several bikes in the past.  This generally happens after upgrading to LED's from halogen bulbs - but I suppose theoretically it could also happen in other applications.  It happens due to the voltage requirement differences between your stock and aftermarket blinkers.

The fix for this is to add a resistor to "slow" the voltage down.  Higher end aftermarket LED blinkers will sometimes have these already baked into their components but you can also splice one in downstream if it bothers you enough.  One company in particular offers a fantastic plug and play piece which I used on my most recent bike and it works great and is a 5 second install (https://tstindustries.com/tst-led-flasher-relay-gen2.html)

You can also look up the model of blinkers you purchased and I bet that same company will offer some kind of resistor to help with the hyperflash.